# How to use ragged-tensor to implement the following loop code in tensorflow2?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, ragged-tensors

```
g=tf.random.normal([1000,627,16,1])
ind1=tf.constant(np.random.randint(100,size=(251,128,128,3)))
ind2=tf.constant(np.random.randint(100,size=(150,128,128,3)))
ind3=tf.constant(np.random.randint(100,size=(100,128,128,3)))
f1=tf.gather_nd(g[0:251]*1.0,ind1)
f2=tf.gather_nd(g[30:150+30]*1.0,ind2)
f3=tf.gather_nd(g[120:120+100]*1.0,ind3)
f=tf.concat([f1,f2,f3],0)
print('debug')
```

The ind1,ind2,ind3 can be merged as a rageed tensor. But the shapes of g used for each ind  are still not uniform. I know one way to solve this problem is to extend ind1, ind2 and ind3 to the same shape of g. But this method  exhausts too much GPU memory.

Is there a method to implement the above codes in one function by using ragged tensor like:
ind=tf.ragged.constant([ind1,ind2,ind3])
f=tf.gather_nd(g,ind)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.